# create corner arc with css

Tags: html, css

How would you create such corner arc using css?

[image]

This is starter template: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rwraXG

I was hoping that I would be able to use black outer div and red inner div, and use border radius to leave just the top left corner showing through. I messed something midway.

```css
.bar {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}

.outer {
  height: 100%;
  width: 8px;
  background-color: black;
}

.inner {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 15px 0px 0px 0px:
}
```

```html
<div class="bar">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modified your codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dRjoow

Essentially, it was a syntax error. You had a colon (:) at the end of your border-radius property like this:

```
.inner{
  ...
  border-radius: 15px 0px 0px 0px:
}
```

instead of a semi colon (;) like this:

```
.inner{
  ...
  border-radius: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

so it wasn't rendering.

Answer (score 2):

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m8wf66u6/

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
<div class="inner">
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: black;
}

.inner {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only problem is the `:` at the end of the last line.

```
border-radius: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
```

Note that you can also use :

```
border-top-left-radius: 15px;
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to do it with 2 DIVs as below:
HTML :

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.outer,.inner{
  width:200px;
  height:80px;
}
.outer {
  background-color:black;
}
.inner {
  background-color:red;
  border-radius:20px 0 0 0; /* numbers are :  top left bottom right*/
}
```

https://codepen.io/FaridNaderi/pen/pwZJyP

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do this with the inner and outer boxes as you have. You would change your css to the below. You don't need to declare the color red on '.bar' because your '.inner' div will be the red portion of this.

```
.bar{
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
}
.outer{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background-color:black;
}
.inner{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background-color:red;
  border-radius: 20px 0 0 0;
}
```

As long as your parent div ('.bar') has a set width and height '.inner' and '.outer' can have width and heights of 100%.

*Please note though that the higher you make '.bar' the better the top left tab will look.